# rename package when installing with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Working on an existing nodejs project, one of packages is not in my control, for example, `public-package`. When I try to publish a new version, I have to deploy with a new package name, such as `my-package`.

For example,

```
{
  ...
    "dependencies": {
    "public-package": "1.0.123",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

In source code, there are lot of lines, such as `require('public-package')`

So how can I use my package, rename it directly when `npm install` without changing the code from `require('public-package')` to `require('my-package')`?

Such as

```
{
  ...
    "dependencies": {
    "public-package": "my-package@1.0.10",   # <= how to make this work?
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Can I do anything to make it work as above code?

Comment: Dig out an old ticket https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2943, seems the owner doesn't like this idea from beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to change the `main` entry in the package.json of `public-package` (located in `node_modules/public-package/package.json`)

See [Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) in the node docs for details of how the `main` entry works. The technique is used to point `require` to a subfolder of a module, but in this case you could adapt it to fit your needs.

```
{ 
  "name" : "public-package",
  "main" : "./public-package.js"
}
```

Change it to

```
{ 
  "name" : "public-package",
  "main" : "/path/to/my-package.js"
}
```

Now each time you do a `require('public-package')`, it loads `my-package` without the need of changing the source code.

To change the entry automatically in `node_modules/public-package/package.json`, you could add a custom [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) to npm that does a search-and-replace in that file.